# How can an accelerating inclined plane prevent a block on it from sliding?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, vectors, free-body-diagram

[image]

If I increase the force $F$, only the normal force $N1$ acting on $m1$ would increase which has no component along the plane, ie. along $m1gsin\theta$, so how would applying this force prevent m1 from sliding?

When I view it from the accelerated frame of the wedge,

[image]

It begins making sense. How is this possible? I'm really confused.

Comment: because forward acceleration of plane induces backwards acceleration reaction force of a body, due to $F_B=-F_A$, then backwards acceleration has vector component aligned up-the-hill, which cancels down-the-hill vector component of weight. Basics is like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Diagram 1 shows the arrangement with the inclined plane stationary.
There are two forces acting on the block, its weight $mg$ and the normal reaction on the block due to the inclined plane $N_1$.
The resultant of theses two forces is $F_1 ( = mg \sin \theta)$ and this force accelerates the block down the slope.

Diagram 2 shows the situation when a force $F$ is applied to the inclined plane and there is no relative movement between the block and the inclined plane.
That is because the resultant of the weight of the block $mg$ and the now increased normal reaction $N_2$ is a horizontal force $F_2$.

If that force $F_2$ on the block produces an acceleration of the block $a$ which is the same as the acceleration of the inclined plane then the block will not move relative to the inclined plane.

When this condition is satisfied $F_2 = ma$ and $F=(m+M)a$

Note that the magnitude of $F$ controls the magnitude of $N_2$ which in turn controls the direction of $F_2$.

If $F$ is larger than in the no relative movement condition then the magnitude of $N_2$ is larger and the block accelerates up the inclined plane whilst if $F$ is smaller then the block accelerates down the slope.

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is that $N_1$ has no component along the inclined plane to oppose gravity's component along the plane i.e. $mgsin\theta$ so intuitively it doesn't make sense how increasing $N_1$ would prevent sliding since it has no component along the plane opposing $mgsin\theta$

Comment: @xasthor There is no component opposing the $mg\sin{\theta}$, but there doesn't need to be. It provides a component of acceleration down the slope. But the normal force at the same time provides a component of acceleration  perpendicular to the slope, moving the block up into the air. And the two component balance so the next

Comment: But the block isn't really lifted into the air momentarily, is it?

Comment: In diagram 2 the vertical component of the normal reaction $N_2$ is equal and opposite to the weight $mg$ so the resultant force is the horizontal component of $N_2$.

Comment: Upvoting for the clear diagrams. =)

Answer (score 2):

What causes the block to slide? That would be gravity.

What tries to prevent this slide? That would be friction.

And friction depends on the normal force $f_k=\mu_k n$.

As you rightfully say, the normal force increases with increasing pushing force $F$, which thus causes increased friction which thus prevents the slide.

---

Is the surface frictionless, then consider the same case purely from an acceleration component point of view:

**With gravity alone**, some normal force is present. It balances the perpendicular gravity component, so there is no acceleration in this direction. Only in the sliding direction is the gravity component not balanced.

**Now *with* the push**, the normal force increases, so it is far larger than necessary to balance the perpendicular gravity component. So in the perpendicular direction there is now acceleration *away* from the surface.

But remember that the parallel gravity component is still there and still unbalanced.

Put this parallel and perpendicular component together and the resulting acceleration is straight ahead (in the pushing direction).

In other words, the moving incline is pushing the block forward and *upwards*, while gravity is pulling it forward and *downwards*. So certainly, this upwards and downwards tendency can balance and only straight forward acceleration remains

Comment: The surfaces here are frictionless. Forgot to mention it. What doesn't make sense to me is that $N_1$ has no component along the inclined plane to oppose gravity's component along the plane i.e. $mgsin\theta$ so intuitively it doesn't make sense how increasing $N_1$ would prevent sliding since it has no component along the plane opposing $mgsin\theta$

Comment: @xasthor Aha. See my update

Comment: But for the two to add up, wouldn't the surface of the inclined plane pushing the block away from the surface cause the block to momentarily be in the air while the component of gravity parallel to the surface pulls it down? Is this true?

Comment: These two things happen at the same time. It is not first pushed "into the air" and then downwards. It happens simultaneously so we only see the resulting effect, which is the straight acceleration.

Comment: Also remember that the block might be pushed in the direction away from the incline, but it will never leave it and "fly off", not even without gravity,sinply because the incline *is moving along with it* at the same straight acceleration (without gravity it would slide upwards while staying in contact)